# Reading a BufferedReader

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

Is there a way I can create some type of listener that listens to see if there is new data in a BufferedReader? I know I can use something like a while loop and keep seeing if it can be read but even in a async task this seems to block.

Basically what I want to do is listen to a sockets input stream for new data.

Comment: I don't really get the question. If you say `String line = myBufferedReader.readLine();` it will block untill there is new input. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Read comments on answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in java.io is blocking-mode. The usual technique is to have a dedicated reading thread.

Comment: while the aync task is running listening for incoming data and I want to send some data it just doesn't happen

Comment: then make that the question. I must say it wasn't very clear. @SmartLemon

Comment: Yeah sorry. Figured it out anyway. I just stopped the listening while sending then started it again.